# Using Promises to test Meteor - Mocha

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing server-side unit tests for a Meteor JS application. I'm using the recommended Mocha framework, with chai assertion library. I had some trouble with chaining async calls with done() callback, so I decided to use meteor/promise. I'm using and johanbrook:publication-collector to collect the published collections.

When I resolve(collections) in the promise, In the subsequent then() I'm able to console.log the gathered collection, but the assert statement wouldn't work. The mocha test simply passes every time I run, even if the assertion should fail the test.

```
it('sample test', function() {
    this.timeout(5000);
    const collector = new PublicationCollector({ userId: Random.id() });
    const some_collection =  Factory.create('some_collection');
    chai.assert.equal(some_collection.details.value, 100);

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        Contracts.getActiveContracts(); // updates some_collection.details.value
        collector.collect('some_collection', function(collections) {
            resolve(collections);
        });
    }).then(function(coll) {
        console.log('collected lots:',coll.some_collection.details);
        chai.assert.equal(null, coll.some_collection); //this is effectively invisible, why?
    });
});

>>I201609-10:12:46.867(-5)? collected: { some_collection: 
I200609-10:12:46.867(-5)?    [ { _id: 'Qh4qQTwKTdHYtpA',
I200609-10:12:46.868(-5)?        owner: 'kkishore',
I201609-10:12:46.868(-5)?        createdAt: Tue Jun 06 2017       10:37:07 GMT-0500 (CDT),
I20160609-10:12:46.868(-5)?        details: [Object] } ] }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What version of Mocha are you using? If I create a test case that schematically reproduces what you are doing, there's no problem `chai.assert.equal` fails, and the error is reported.

Comment: @louis I used "meteor add practicalmeteor:mocha" to install      `.meteor/versions             
practicalmeteor:mocha@2.4.5_2
practicalmeteor:mocha-core@0.1.4`

Comment: When I add  `.catch(function(err) { 
console.log(err); 
});`  to the Promise, I'm able to see the assertion error, I don't understand  why the web-client is not showing this assertion error.

Comment: I suggest producing a [mcve] so that people can run your code.

Comment: @louis please take a look at , [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735838/promises-in-mocha-unit-tests)  I'm very new to meteor, and promises, perhaps I'm missing something very basic.