# Promises in Mocha Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise, mocha.js

This question is related to [Using Promises to test Meteor - Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730569/using-promises-to-test-meteor-mocha?noredirect=1#comment62934988_37730569)

Like Louis suggested, I have replicated the same issue in a smaller program, so that you can reproduce this. And in this one too Mocha doesn't care about the assert statement. The catch block of the promises gets this error.

**/server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

export const myCollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');

export const addObject = function (id) {
    myCollection.insert({
        name: 'test ' + id
    });
}

Meteor.publish('mycollection', function() {
    return myCollection.find({});
});
```

**/server/main.test.js**

```
/**
 * Created by enigma on 6/9/16.
 */
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { PublicationCollector } from 'meteor/johanbrook:publication-collector';
import { Promise } from 'meteor/promise';
import { assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';
import { addObject } from '../server/main.js';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    describe('test mocha promise', function() {
        before(function() {
            addObject(Random.id());
        });
        it('collects  myCollection test', function() {
            const collector = new PublicationCollector({ userId: Random.id()});

            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                    collector.collect('mycollection', function (collections) {
                        resolve(collections);
                    });
            }).then(function(coll) {
                chai.assert.notEqual(coll, null);
                chai.assert.equal(coll, null);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log('error:', err.stack);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**console output**

```
=> Meteor server restarted
I20160609-18:31:14.546(-5)? MochaRunner.runServerTests: Starting server side tests with run id GK3WqWY4Ln9u6vmsg
I20160609-18:31:14.598(-5)? error: AssertionError: expected { Object (mycollection) } to equal null
I20160609-18:31:14.598(-5)?     at Function.assert.equal (packages/practicalmeteor_chai.js:2635:10)
I20160609-18:31:14.598(-5)?     at test/main.test.js:25:29
I20160609-18:31:14.598(-5)?     at /Users/enigma/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.6.7.1d67q83++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:33:40
W20160609-18:31:14.607(-5)? (STDERR) MochaRunner.runServerTests: failures: 0
```

Comment: You should print the stack trace of the received error, it can help find where the problem is.

Comment: I'm not getting any stack trace, `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined]` this is all I get

Comment: try `console.error(err.stack)` or even remove the catch, if I remember correctly mocha prints the stack trace

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it/23803744#23803744

Comment: @user3 I've added the stack trace. If I remove the catch nothing happens, mocha doesn't print the stack trace.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum could you please explain a bit more, I have wrapped what I need in a promise and I'm using then().

Answer (score 1):

you need to either throw in the catch or remove the catch, so that mocha gets the error too. currently since you catch the error, the promise mocha gets is resolved.

Below was my old answer, before the question change
ps: it looks like I misunderstood what was a publish for meteor so the bellow answer is not really correct

---

The error you're encountering is because "mycollection" is not published

I is probably because `Meteor.publish('mycollection');` [is an async function](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe), to the collection is not published yet when you test it.

you should do the publish in a `before()` before your test

Here is an example of how you can wait the publish to finish in a before

Comment: thanks for pointing me towards publish, I forgot to pass the callback function, edited the code above.

Comment: I edited my answer too to show a code example of what I meant, also beware with the `addObject` you added, it's async so you should return a promise to tell mocha when it's done

Comment: I edited again my answer, for you new question, and to add that I misunderstood things

Comment: I see what you mean, but for some reason mocha doesn't catch the assertion error, even after removing the catch  `I20160609-21:05:37.637(-5)? MochaRunner.runServerTests: Starting server side tests with run id qdf9sKXiaZ2TzTB8w
W20160609-21:05:37.673(-5)? (STDERR) MochaRunner.runServerTests: failures: 0`

Comment: Since you have `assert.equal` and `assert.notEqual` it should be the expected result, no?

Comment: yes, only problem is that mocha wouldn't catch the assertion error, could it be a bug?

Comment: `it('test', function(done) {
    
       return new Promise({
          //do something  
        }).then(function(){
            done();
        }).catch(function(err){
            done(err);
       });
   })`

Answer (score 0):

I read this in a discussion, this works for me, although some are discouraging use of 'done' callback with promises.

```
it('collects  myCollection test', function(done) {
        const collector = new PublicationCollector({ userId: Random.id()});

        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                collector.collect('mycollection', function (collections) {
                    resolve(collections);
                });
        }).then(function(coll) {
            chai.assert.notEqual(coll, null);
            chai.assert.equal(coll, null);
            done();
        }).catch(function(err) {
            done(err);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use PublicationCollector like this:

```
it('should publish 2 documents', async () => {
    const collector = new PublicationCollector({ 'userId': Random.id() });

    const testPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        collector.collect('myDocuments',
            (collections) => {
                resolve(collections.myDocuments.length);
            });
    });

    const result = await testPromise;

    assert.equal(result, 1);
});
```

Adapted from [here](https://staxmanade.com/2015/11/testing-asyncronous-code-with-mochajs-and-es7-async-await/).

This test fails relatively gracefully.